# Why is color shown correctly in WPF DataGrid on my computer but not on other computers?

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is the form on my computer. I'm changing the Setter Property for Background and Foreground in the first column is color coded:
[my form with color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrVuX.png) Here is the same form on another computer: [Image without color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anCMR.png).

I'm not new to C# but I am new to WPF. I cannot figure out why no one else can see the color.

Thank you for any assistance,
Dan

I'm using C# VS 2022, below is my XAML for the form to have the color. Is there a DLL reference I need to include for other computers to see the XAML defined color or should I code this differently?

```
<Window x:Class="WarningsFix.HKS.MainWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WarningsFix.HKS"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="1000" Height="306" Title="Warnings By Severity" Background="#FFE8D1D1" WindowStartupLocation="Manual" Topmost="True"  WindowStyle= "ToolWindow" ResizeMode="CanResize">
    <Grid Margin="10,10,0,3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" MouseDoubleClick="DataGrid1_MouseDoubleClick" IsReadOnly="true" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0,5
                  ,10,53" PreviewKeyDown="DataGrid1_PreviewKeyDown" ToolTip="Double-click a warning name access each type">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding Severity}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF00"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="2">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="3">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Count" Binding="{Binding Count}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Warning Name" Binding="{Binding WarningName}" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button x:Name="btnClose" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,14" Click="btnClose_Click" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" Width="62" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        <Label x:Name="lblWarningCount" Content="Total Number of Warnings:" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,11" FontSize="14" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnExport" Content="Export" Margin="0,0,10,14" Click="btnExport_Click" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="62" ToolTip="Export the data to a CSV file"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You may want to check again the images, they are the same

Comment: So sorry, see 'Image without color'

Comment: I don't think that this is related to this XAML code. it makes more sense if this is related to your severity assessment.  You should use a logger (or debugger if possible) to inspect the severity values, to check if they are correct. Maybe the values are `0`.

Comment: Whatever the input for your severity assessment is, this input source might behave different on other machines, thus leading to invalid/unexpected severity values. I would take a closer look at the data input and processing part.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I'm using very simple string values. Thank you for looking at the issue and have a great holiday!